Probable bug in DumpMachine() Quantum API function of Microsoft Quantum Platform
According to help from Microsoft Learn, the binding of Qubit[] array to its equivalent ket vector representation is such that the qubit with index 0 becomes the rightmost qubit in the ket vector representation. So we expect that the output of the following Q# program be $|001\rangle$, but this is not the case.
namespace Quantum.Demo {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;

    @EntryPoint()
    operation CreateStateVector001() : Unit {
        use qba = Qubit[3];

        // initializing qubits
        Reset(qba[2]);
        Reset(qba[1]);
        X(qba[0]);  // The LSB becomes a 1

        // Display the state of the qubits
        DumpMachine();

        // Reset all qubits before releasing them
        ResetAll(qba);
    }
}

Please help me understand why.

Finally I found the reason behind this confusion: It seems that the DumpMachine() operation lists the quantum system qubits in the reverse order into ket vector representation which is unfortunately not mentioned in Microsoft documentations (as far as I know).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any good and detailed documentation fot DumpMachine() operation. Also, Microsoft didn't answer my help request. This answer is just based on inference from my experience.
